# how do i populate a php array from one column of an sql database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Lets say I have a mysql database called "pcode" with only one table, called "uk_postcodes" and I want to populate my array with only the first column, called "postcodes". What is missing from the following code:

```
    //link to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    mysql_select_db('pcode'); 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ukpostcodes`";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

$var = array();
```

Comment: usual way to get the data from database is missing, which you used to use 1000 times already, but forgot here for whatever reason.

Answer (score 7):

```
$sql = "SELECT postcodes FROM ukpostcodes";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$var = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $var[] = $row['postcodes'];
}
```